# Getting parse error while running below BASH script

Tags: bash, shell, azure-devops-rest-api

Getting parse error while running below BASH script, upon doing the shell check its throwing error at **-d** '{ with  `-d '{ -- SC2016: Expressions don't expand in single quotes, use double quotes for that.`

But using double quotes is again not helping, I have used somewhat similar script with single quotes at -d and it has worked fine. Any help would be really appreciated. Just to add I am doing shell check from here https://www.shellcheck.net/

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter PAT Token"
read -r PAT

echo "Enter Organization name"
read -r OrganizationName

echo "Enter Project ID"
read -r projectId

echo "Enter Repo name"
read -r RepoName

echo "Enter Repo ID"
read -r RepoID

  "Pipeline=$(curl --write-out "%{http_code}\n" -X POST \
        -u  :"$PAT" "http://dev.azure.com/""${OrganizationName}""/""${projectId}""/_apis/build/definitions?api-version=5.0" \
        -H  "Accept: application/json" \
        -H  "Content-Type: application/json" \
        -d '{
                "name" : "TEST-PIPELINE";
                "repository" : {
                "url" : https://""${OrganizationName}""@dev.azure.com/""${OrganizationName}""/""${projectId}""/_git/""${RepoName}"";
                "defaultBranch" : "refs/heads/master";
                "id" : "'"$RepoID"'";
                "type" : "TfsGit";
                                };
        "process" : {
                "yamlFilename": "'"${RepoName}/azure-pipeline.yml"'";
                "type" : 2;
                };
                        "path": "\\";
                        "type" : "build";
                }' --output PipelineOutput.txt --silent)"

        echo "Output: $(Pipeline)"
```

Comment: That's not how json looks like. Like _at all_. Research json syntax. `"Pipeline=` that's now how you assign a variable and `$(Pipeline)"` that's not how you reference a variable. Research a good shell  _introduction_ that will explain _basics_ of shell scripting - command substitution and variable expansion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you have copied comes from this line:

```
"url" : https://""${OrganizationName}""@dev.azure.com/""${OrganizationName}""/""${projectId}""/_git/""${RepoName}"";
```

It need some extra single quotes, similar to what you are using elsewhere:

```
"url" : https://"'"${OrganizationName}"'"@dev.azure.com/"'"${OrganizationName}"'"/"'"${projectId}"'"/_git/"'"${RepoName}"'";
```